# Widget Not Updating?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

This is only my second time using widgets, and first time using buttons on it... or anything other than just TextViews in general.

So basically all I have is a widget... When I click it it doesn't do anything and it never updates. Why? Confused... :P

So, here is my WidgetAct onUpdate code:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context c, AppWidgetManager awm, int[] appWidgetIds){
    Log.i("IN","onUpdate");
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);

    Intent twitter_intent = new Intent(c,TwitterUpdate.class);
    twitter_intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_TWITTER);

    Intent fb_intent = new Intent(c,FBUpdate.class);
    fb_intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_FB);

    //Intent curr = new Intent(c,WidgetAct.class);
    //curr.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_WA);

    PendingIntent twitter_pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, twitter_intent, 0);
    PendingIntent fb_pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c,0,fb_intent,0);

    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tweet, twitter_pi);
    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.fb, fb_pi);

    awm.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, rv);
}
```

Now here is my manifest (or the important part):

```
 <receiver android:name="WidgetAct">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="com.laytproducts.IN.WidgetAct.ACTION_WIDGET_FB" />
            <action android:name="com.laytproducts.IN.WidgetAct.ACTION_WIDGET_TWITTER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/winfo"/>
    </receiver>
```

Here is my xml for the widget provider:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth = "220dp"
android:minHeight = "72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget">
```

Here is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout android:background="@drawable/inwidget" android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageButton android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/twitterlogo" android:layout_marginTop="17dp" android:id="@+id/tweet" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/facebooklogo" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/fb" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tweet" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tweet" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tweet" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp"></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Kind of a lot of code... but I literally have NO reason to believe that I broke something XD... but that is because my widget knowledge is minimal.

Hopefully its a small mistake I over looked.
Thanks all,
Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the explanation in the SDK [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE), the `onUpdate()` method is designed to respond to the `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast, which will be sent in conditions below:

> Sent when it is time to update your AppWidget.
>   This may be sent in response to a new instance for this AppWidget provider having been instantiated, the requested update interval having lapsed, or the system booting.

In your code, you set the action `com.laytproducts.IN.WidgetAct.ACTION_WIDGET_FB`, so the `onUpdate()` won't be called.  I haven't used `getActivity` in widget, but I have used `getBroadcast` and it works well.

```
PendingIntent fb_pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c,0,fb_intent,0);
```

I think you should handle your click event in the `onReceive()` method. Please note that the `AppWidgetProvider` extends from `BroadcastReceiver`, so only `onReceive()` will be called(in the `onReceive()` in the source code of `AppWidgetProvider`, `onUpdate()` is called inside. That's why we have `onUpdate()`). You should do something like:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals("com.laytproducts.IN.WidgetAct.ACTION_WIDGET_FB")) {
           //handle your click event here

        }

}
```

This is what I did in my widget. Hope it helps.

Comment: So I finally got it to actually go through onUpdate now... It was a typo in the manifest. Now my buttons dont do anything, even after being assigned onClicks. my onReceive doesn't even get called when i click them

Comment: Nevermind. Just ended up using .getActivity and it worked. It was really just a typo issue and organization issue that led to it not working

Comment: thanks for your reply. it's great you solved the problem and I also learned something:)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your widget to update, you should have to set the time interval in  "updatePeriodMillis" field in the XML file .But remember ,the minimum time interval for updating using this method is 30 min.

Comment: You can use Alarm manager service if you want to reduce the updation interval to less than 30 min.

Comment: Well essentially I don't want it to "update". I just want it to wait for a button click... So would it be best to just stick that code in the onEnabled method?

Comment: OnEnabled method will be invoked when you are launching your widget for the first time and onDisable will be called when you deletes the last instance of your widget. On enabled wont be aclled when you create a second instance of your widget.

Comment: hmm... the problem is i need 'AppWidgetManager awm, int[] appWidgetIds' to set up the buttons... So maybe I should set the update to 1sec then set it programmatically to like 30min? Is that possible?

Comment: Can you explain your requirement clearly..I think you want to start an activity on button click..is it so?

Comment: Yes. That is example what my requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
  RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
  Intent one = new Intent(context, TwitterUpdate.class);     
  Intent two = new Intent(context, FBUpdate.class);   
  PendingIntent p1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, one, 0);
  PendingIntent p2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, two, 0);
  remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.twitter_pi, p1);
  remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.fb_pi, p2);
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what I have already xD the problem is that its NOT getting into onUpdate

Comment: are u using any configuration activity?

Comment: I dont know what you mean. So that must mean no.
Nothing is wrong with the activities. No even the onEnabled is being called. so ya.